# How often does the AFH_CHANNEL_MAP get updated during a bluetooth connection

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

Bluetooth transmissions incorporate a frequency hopping selection kernel (FHS) that constantly changes the frequency of the Bluetooth radio during transmission and receiving. This is further complemented by the Adaptive Frequency Hopping (AFH) protocol that is used in pair with FHS. AFH helps the Bluetooth RT avoid busy channels and keep multiple connections running, along with using Time Division Duplex (TDD).

I've been reading through the Bluetooth Core Specifications for awhile now. They mention that the AFH algorithm is implementation specific. However, they do not mention how often the AFH_CHANNEL_MAP packet should be sent to the slave device to update the AFH map. Just that it *shall* be sent.

Is the timing for this AFH map update also implementation specific? Or is there a regular schedule that devices send to update the AFH channel map?

Furthermore, is there any difference in the FHS for Bluetooth Classic and Bluetooth Low Energy?